# Spring's @Scheduled(fixedDelay=...) stops at midnight

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring Boot application that uses a `@Scheduled` annotation with a fixed delay. The annotation is used in different classes with different delays. However, at midnight every day all scheduled tasks stop running.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I can't find any explanation online.

(I am using version 2.0.2.RELEASE of Spring Boot and 5.0.6.RELEASE of Spring Core.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can I see one of your scheduled cron expression that stops?

Comment: Make sure that the OS you are running on doesn't kill threads, it might kill the actual scheduling thread.

Comment: The @Scheduled annotation doesn't use the cron feature. It looks like this: @Scheduled(initialDelay = 10000, fixedDelay = 60000).

Comment: I'm not sure how to see if my OS is killing threads, but I will dump the Java threads today before and after midnight to see if some are disappearing. I don't think the OS is doing it because I have some long running threads not managed by Spring and they continue to work. FYI, I am running CentOS 7 inside of a Docker container. The host is Debian 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who replied.

As it turns out, this was not an issue with Spring. It appeared the tasks stopped because the logs stopped. What really happened was that our scripts that tail the logs were not smart enough to handle log files that roll at midnight (face palm).

Comment: Hi Steven, can you explain a little more on how the problem is solved. I am facing the same issue with my spring scheduler from some time now.

Comment: @ManojKSardana Did you resolve your problem? I have same problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean about stopping running.

But the first work you need to do is starting your schedules on different threads and put them into a queue.

If stopping means suspending for a while,then you create a new schedule that make other schedules sleep some time at midnight.Maybe the new schedule should have be started when the thread are sleeping,and the way to prevent is to make sure only one schedule(I mean same kind of schedule) could be put in the queue at the same time.

If you just mean kill all other schedule at midnight,you just need to start your midnight schedules and kill others.

So sorry about my poor English,hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already set a pool size greater than the number of scheduled tasks on both the scheduler and executor. If I understand correctly, that means they should be on different threads.

Comment: When I said stopping, I meant the tasks are completely stopped as far as I can tell. Yesterday I left the application up for more than 8 hours after the last execution and there was never any more activity from the tasks.

Comment: The tasks cant start again?Were you shutdown the thread pool?If the thread pool is still running,what if you execute a task by a Scheduler like ThreadPoolTaskScheduler?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
 void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
   System.out.println(
  "Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 
 1000);
  }
```

In this case, the duration between the end of last execution and the start of next execution is fixed. The task always waits until the previous one is finished.

This option should be used when it’s mandatory that the previous execution is completed before running again.

So maintain the delay such a way that the previous execution completed.

Hope it helps.